# Internet Explorer 9 auto "feeling lucky" for gmail bing search

Tags: internet-explorer-9

When I'm at school and using school computers, I have to use has IE9. When I want to access my Gmail, I type in "gmail" in the URL bar, causing IE9 to do a bing search.

The page half loads (As in, loads just about everything but the search results) and then opens my Gmail, similar to google's "I'm feeling lucky". My question is this: Why?

IE9 doesn't have the URL of gmail, as I can watch the bing search load, followed by the url changing to Gmail, and it only seems to happen for Gmail, having tired with searching Google and Facebook in the same method.

The computer is running Windows 7 with Windows Aero disabled, and limited account privileges.

While its a neat feature, I would like to known what causes it to happen.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're using OpenDNS? This behaviour was reported on their forums almost a year ago:
http://forums.opendns.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=10517

Specifically see [this post](http://forums.opendns.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=10517#Item_16):

> OpenDNS is hijacking the search if the url has the src=ie9tr parameter which used if you have "top results" enabled.

A workaround is to disable "Top results" for the Bing search provider:

- Go to Tools -> "Manage add-ons"
- In the new window, click on "Search Providers", then click on Bing
- At the bottom, click on "Disable top result in address bar"
- Click **OK**

Another workaround is to stop using OpenDNS.

Comment: Is there some kinda list around on what this applys to? Or is it automatic? Because it seems strange that its only working for Gmail

Comment: I'm not aware of any such list. But it also works with "yahoo", "msn" and "amazon", for example, and I'm sure there are more examples.

Comment: It didn't work for Yahoo, but did for Amazon, so i think its set to work if you've been to the site before. However I went to Yahoo, still didn't work. Maybe it's also affected by the amount of times you go to a website? Would be interesting to find out...